# SRC= for jquery-ui.min.js?

Tags: jquery-ui

I've included jquery.tools.min.js from jquerytools.org for my project like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"</script>
```

I would like to do the same for `jquery-ui.min.js`, but not sure what the url for this file should be.  Does anyone know?  I don't want to host this file locally.  I want to get that from popular servers like jquerytools.org, google, yahoo etc...  Then there's a greater likelihood the files are cached in user's browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From here:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js